# SendGrid List-Unsubscribe does not show the "unsubscribe" button on the mailbox

Tags: gmail, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, list-unsubscribe

I was working my way using [this guide](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/list-unsubscribe).

The guide mentions that this feature should work both with and without subscription-tracking:

> It is possible to use the List-Unsubscribe header even if you do not want to use subscription tracking. This is useful for users who want to provide their recipients an easy way to unsubscribe from their emails without relying on SendGrid’s tracking features

However, in neither case I see the "unsubscribe" button next to the sender name in the Gmail mailbox.

I built my request as I usually do and added the extra header to it. Something of the form:

```
Mail mail = new Mail();
/* build mail... */
Request request = new Request();
request.setBaseUri(baseUri);
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("/v3/mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());
/* set auth/accept/misc headers... */
request.addHeader("List-Unsubscribe", "<mailto:unsubscribeexampexample@example.com>, <http://www.unsubscribe.example.com>");
return sg.api(request);
```

Like I said, neither with nor without subscription-tracking I get the "unsubscribe" link. Also note that I tried this with their actual links in their example link/mailto, just to confirm.

Any ideas what is being missed here?

Comment: try to send the email to your private gmail if your company working with google workspace, it works for us, the work email didn't get this also because it was the same source as the test email.